# Create a Tree Path during aggregation using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using spark to aggregate my data.

Let's say I have a table:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | value | country |
+----+-------+---------+
|  0 |     2 | us      |
|  1 |     5 | us      |
|  2 |     1 | ca      |
|  3 |     3 | us      |
|  4 |     8 | ca      |
+----+-------+---------+
```

And I'd like to groupBy data by country so it becomes:

```
+------+-------+---------+----------+
|  id  | value | country | treePath |
+------+-------+---------+----------+
| null |    24 | null    | /        | <- total row
| us   |    15 | null    | /us      |
| 0    |     2 | us      | /us/0    |
| 1    |     5 | us      | /us/1    |
| 3    |     3 | us      | /us/3    |
| ca   |     9 | null    | /ca      |
| 2    |     1 | ca      | /ca/2    |
| 4    |     8 | ca      | /ca/4    |
+------+-------+---------+----------+
```

which has an additional column to display the tree path.

I'm thinking to modify child rows during aggregation to reference its direct parent and recursively build the treePath. Is this viable approach?

Comment: I will definitely help you if you show that you have tried it yourself. Please share what you've tried. You will have to use multiple aggregations and multiple unions to get the desired output

Comment: Yea, I have tried to update rows first then aggregate and union two df; I may need multi-level groupBy's for more complicated tables. I'm wondering if there is a way to write formulas to build the column instead of manually repeat aggregations.

Comment: can you update the question with your tryings?

Comment: how are you getting 24 and 15 in your result dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is *create three dataframes*

a *total dataframe* with `id` and `country` populated as `null` and `value` as *sum of all the values* and `treePath` as *root*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
//total dataframe for root tree path
val totalDf = df.select(lit(null).as("id"), sum("value").as("value"), lit(null).as("country"))
                  .withColumn("treePath", lit("/"))
```

a *grouped dataframe* with `id` and `country` populated as *country value* and `value` populated as *sum of grouped values* and `treePath` as *home*

```
//grouped dataframe for home treepath for every group
val groupedDf = df.groupBy(col("Country").as("id")).agg(sum("value").as("value"), first(col("country")).as("country"))
                  .withColumn("treePath", concat_ws("/", lit(""), col("country")))
```

And *original dataframe* populated with `treePath` of *country and id*, and finally `union` all of them

```
//union all three dataframe for final treePath column
df.withColumn("treePath", concat_ws("/", lit(""), col("country"), col("id")))
  .union(totalDf)
  .union(groupedDf)
```

Thats it. And you should have *output dataframe* as

```
+----+-----+-------+--------+
|id  |value|country|treePath|
+----+-----+-------+--------+
|null|19.0 |null   |/       |
|ca  |9.0  |ca     |/ca     |
|2   |1    |ca     |/ca/2   |
|4   |8    |ca     |/ca/4   |
|us  |10.0 |us     |/us     |
|0   |2    |us     |/us/0   |
|1   |5    |us     |/us/1   |
|3   |3    |us     |/us/3   |
+----+-----+-------+--------+
```